# Append all the files from different VM's to a particular one?

Tags: linux, scripting, scp

I want to get particular file from different Vm's and get it appended to a single file.I tried it like this

```
scp admin@data-1:/var/log/elasticsearch/cluster.log /home/itadmin/logstash/logstash-2.4.1/slowlogs.log

scp admin@data-2:/var/log/elasticsearch/cluster.log /home/itadmin/logstash/logstash-2.4.1/slowlogs.log
```

But the problem is it is overwriting the files . How can i append it in the same way?

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a temporary file and do it in two steps like this:

```
scp admin@data-1:/var/log/elasticsearch/cluster.log /tmp/x; cat /tmp/x >> destinationfile.log
```

Or use `ssh` and `cat` like this

```
ssh admin@data-1 cat /var/log/elasticsearch/cluster.log  >> destinationfile.log
```

This second approach works since ssh is build so that you can run commands on the remote machine. In this case we run `cat` on the desired file on the remote machine and *collect* the output locally.

Comment: Thanks .. for doing ssh i have enabled the usernames and passwords for all the VM's . Is it possible to use the username and password in `ssh admin@data-1 cat /var/log/elasticsearch/cluster.log  >> destinationfile.log`

Comment: Yes, that works!

Comment: `ssh` and `scp` are basically the same thing at some base level. About `scp` from `man scp`: _It uses ssh(1) for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as ssh(1)._